# Load state notifier before runApp using riverpods 1.0 and vrouter

Tags: flutter

I have a user state notifier that manages login and logout. If the user is logged in when the app starts I redirect to a logged in route. Because it needs to get the user from hive it is not ready in the time. How can I wait for the state notifier to do its thing before runApp starts the app?

this is what it looks like

```
VGuard(
  afterEnter: (BuildContext context, __, ___) async {
    String currentPath = VRouter.of(context).path;


    /// Wait for state notifier to not be "UserInitial"


    // If path is base
    if (currentPath == '/') {
      // Redirect
      if (userStateNotifier is UserLoggedOut) {
        context.vRouter.to('/logged-out');
      } else if (userStateNotifier is UserLoggedIn) {
        context.vRouter.to('/logged-in');
      }
    }
  },
  stackedRoutes: [
    VWidget(
      path: '/',
      widget: const SplashScreen(),
    ),
  ],
),
```